# undefined method `model_name' for DisplayPhotoUploader:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave

I am trying to loop through the images to display in a gallery as below.

```
<%= @venue.venue_photos.each do |photo| %>
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
            <div class="widget">
              <div class="thumbnail">
                <%= link_to(image_tag(photo.display_photo.url(:medium)), photo.display_photo, :class => 'thumb-zoom lightbox') %>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <% end %>
```

am getting the error while trying to retrieve the image url from carrierwave as a result of the looping.

```
undefined method `model_name' for DisplayPhotoUploader:Class
```

Comment: At which line that error is coming?

Comment: This error will be caused by Rails trying to access the `model_name` attribute of a data object. The problem is you're not passing a typical Ruby object; you're passing a naked `Class`. To fix this, you need to pass an instance of a `Class Object`, such as `@photo = Photo.first`

Comment: @Pavan <%= link_to(image_tag(photo.display_photo.url(:medium)), photo.display_photo, :class => 'thumb-zoom lightbox') %>

Comment: @RichPeck should i do that after the if do?

Comment: No, it looks like a CarrierWave problem to me - are you using Carrierwave or Paperclip?

Comment: CarrierWave. yeah carrierwave give the imageurl based on the config for the models. so i need to pass that when i do photo.display_photo.url(:medium)

Answer (score 0):

[link_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) helper creates a link i.e., an `anchor element <a href="..">..</a>` using the arguments passed to it. First argument is used to display clickable text/ image, second argument takes a set of `options` that creates the `url` (i.e. `href`) which this `<a> element` would be linking to and the last one `html_options` takes any html attributes related to the `<a> element`.

In your case, you passed the first and third arguments correctly BUT the second argument is incorrect `photo.display_photo` is not going to create any `url` as it will just fetch the attribute named `display_photo` of instance `photo`. This is resulting in the error

`undefined method 'model_name' for DisplayPhotoUploader:Class`

To resolve this, pass a valid `url` which you wish to route to upon clicking the image.

Run `rake routes` on command prompt to check the list of available routes for your application.

```
<%= link_to(image_tag(photo.display_photo.url(:medium)), photo.display_photo, :class => 'thumb-zoom lightbox') %>
####                                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^       
####                                                      Change this
```

Comment: @Kriti Carrierwave gives you the URL automatically when you do the Model.column but here since i am looping the model has not been set. any idea how i can pass the url of the image. since its a light box the link is to the image which gets picked up by the plugin to display a popup of the image

Comment: any suggestions for this?